# Solving for X in the following equation

Tags: r

Its been a while since I have had to solve for x in a given equation. I would really appreciate any help!

```
1) .0137672 = (x-777)/(x+777)/2

2) .0137672 * 2 = (x-777)/(x+777)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are excellent online tools to solve equations like this, and some are providing the step-by-step operations to get the answer. Cymath is an example.

Since you are looking to solve a specific equation, here is the detailed [solution](https://www.cymath.com/answer?q=.0137672%20%3D%20(x-777)%2F(x%2B777)%2F2).

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried to find something like this but I probably was not using the best search terms.